# filter out data union type array `(User | null)[]` to single type `User[]`

Tags: typescript, firebase, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I was trying to filter out nulled array values from array `(User | null)[]` but still, the returned value still have the type `(User | null)[]`, i was hoping for `User[]`

I have this function that formats returned data from firestore which transforms all field that is `Timestamp` type to `Date` type:

```
export const formatDoc = <T extends FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>(
  doc: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<T>,
): T | null => {
  const data = doc.data();

  if (!data) {
    return null;
  }

  return _.mapValues(data, (v: any) =>
    v instanceof firestore.Timestamp ? v.toDate() : v,
  );
};
```

and also i have a function for multiple docs:

```
export const formatDocs = <T extends FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>(
  docs: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<T>[],
): (T | null)[] => docs.map(formatDoc);
```

and im using the above function to get user collection:

```
const collection = await firestore().collection('Users').where('role', '==', role).get()
const users = formatDocs<User>(collection.docs)
```

which the users variable get the `(User | null)[]` type

please help...
here's the `User` interface:

```
export interface User {
  id: string
  name: string
  role: 'admin' | 'user'
  dateCreated: Timestamp | Date
  dateUpdated: Timestamp | Date
}
```